# UILabel placement in MKAnnotationView changed iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, ios11

In a class that extends `MKAnnotationView`, a `UILabel` is created and added as a child.  It is given constraints to be placed inside the parent view with 5px padding on each side.

This view looks fine in iOS 10.2, but in iOS 11 the `UILabel` seems to ignore the constraints and be positioned at (0, 0) within the parent view (though constraints appear to be active in debug view).

Here are the two versions:

[iOS 10.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qq0E.png)

[iOS 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PMHd.png)

I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why...  Any ideas what could be the cause of this?

NOTE:  When I set the constraints to top=superview.top + 0, the `UILabel` actually has a y of `-5px` and extends above the parent `MKAnnotationView`.  So it appears the boundaries are 5px off in the `iOS 11` version.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: I ended up working around the issue by position the label via setting `frame` instead of using layout constraints.  Still unsure about the exact cause of the issue but this worked for the time being.